# Spring autowired collection of qualified beans

Tags: java, spring, collections, dependency-injection, autowired

I have some Spring @Components with @Qualifier annotations, let's say it's in example "A" and "B". I want to inject them (using only annotations) into List. How can I do that ?

```
@Component
public class WhatIHave {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("A")
    private MyType firstBean;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("B")
    private MyType secondBean;
    ....
}

@Component
public class WhatIWantToHave {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("A", "B") //something like that
    private List<MyType> beans;
    ...
}
```

Do I need to make it in @Configuration class ?

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("A")
    private MyType firstBean;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("B")
    private MyType secondBean;

    @Bean
    public List<MyType> beans() {
        return Lists.newArrayList(firstBean, secondBean);
    }
}
```

Or there is another way to do that ?

Comment: Just remove the `@Qualifier` from the `@Autowired` list.

Comment: I know that @Qualifier("A", "B") is incorrect syntax but it's just an idea that I'm looking for instead of configuration class that I've presented.

Comment: Look for this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36262825/binding-annotation-in-spring/36277309#36277309)

Answer (score 0):

`@Qualifier` is to know which bean is qualify to autowired on a field in case of same type beans so why not:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("A")
private MyType firstBean;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("B")
private MyType secondBean;
```

then:

```
List<MyType> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(firstBean);
list.add(secondBean);
```

Comment: That makes a job but isn't nice solution because requires adding new fields to the class. Adding new fields to @Configuration class is better in my opinion. But I was wondering about such only annotation based solution.

Answer (score 0):

How about this workaround

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
@Component
public class TypeCollector implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {

        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    public <T> List<T> getBeans(Class<T> clazz, String... names) {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String name : names) {
            list.add(applicationContext.getBean(name, clazz));
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

The you can autowire the TypeCollector and ask for the beans runtime. The disadvantage is that you will get NoSuchBeanDefinitionException at runtime, and you have to use bean names instead of qualifier.

Comment: Much more code than @Configuration class in my opinion