# Java Spring Boot scheduled jobs

Tags: java, scheduler

I have an app with some jobs and I want to keep these jobs in the database for better maintenance.

The app is structured like this:

DATABASE:

```
CREATE TABLE jobs_config (
    id int8 NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    job_name varchar NOT NULL,
    scheduled_value varchar NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT jobs_config_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT jobs_config_name_un UNIQUE (job_name)
);
insert into jobs_config(job_name, scheduled_value) values('DeleteExpiredTokenJob', '0 0 10 * * MON');
```

JAVA SPRING BOOT:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "jobs_config")
public class JobsConfig {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "job_name")
    private String jobName;

    private String scheduledValue;

    public JobsConfig() {
    }

    public JobsConfig(String jobName, String scheduledValue) {
        this.jobName = jobName;
        this.scheduledValue = scheduledValue;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getJobName() {
        return jobName;
    }

    public void setJobName(String jobName) {
        this.jobName = jobName;
    }

    public String getScheduledValue() {
        return scheduledValue;
    }

    public void setScheduledValue(String scheduledValue) {
        this.scheduledValue = scheduledValue;
    }
}

@Service
public class JobSchedulerService implements SchedulingConfigurer {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JobSchedulerService.class);

    @Autowired
    JobsConfigRepository jobsConfigRepository;

    @Autowired
    DeleteExpiredTokenJob deleteExpiredTokenJob;

    @Autowired
    TestJob testJob;

    @Bean
    public TaskScheduler poolScheduler() {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        scheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("ThreadPoolTaskScheduler");
        scheduler.setPoolSize(1);
        scheduler.initialize();
        return scheduler;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        taskRegistrar.setTaskScheduler(poolScheduler());
        listJobList();
//        refreshJobList( poolScheduler());
    }

    public void listJobList() {
        List<JobsConfig>  jobsList = jobsConfigRepository.findAll();
        for (JobsConfig jobName : jobsList) {
            switch (jobName.getJobName()) {
                case "DeleteExpiredTokenJob":
                    scheduleJob(poolScheduler(), deleteExpiredTokenJob, jobName.getJobName());
                    break;
                case "TestJob":
                    scheduleJob(poolScheduler(), testJob, jobName.getJobName());
                    break;
                default:
                    logger.info(String.format("JOB NOT FOUND [%s]", jobName.getJobName()));
            }
        }
    }

    public void scheduleJob(TaskScheduler scheduler, JobInterface jobInterface, String jobName){
        scheduler.schedule(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                jobInterface.jobCode();
            }
        }, new Trigger(){
            @Override
            public Date nextExecutionTime(TriggerContext triggerContext) {
                Optional <JobsConfig> job = jobsConfigRepository.findByJobName(jobName);
                String cronExp = job.get().getScheduledValue();
                return new CronTrigger(cronExp).nextExecutionTime(triggerContext);
            }
        });
    }
    //THIS IS WHAT I'VE TRIED !
    /*private void refreshJobList(TaskScheduler scheduler){
        scheduler.schedule(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" The Task2 executed at "+ new Date());
                listJobList();
            }
        }, new Trigger(){
            @Override
            public Date nextExecutionTime(TriggerContext triggerContext) {
                String cronExp="0/10 * * * * ?";//Can be pulled from a db . This will run every minute
                return new CronTrigger(cronExp).nextExecutionTime(triggerContext);
            }
        });
    }*/

}
```

The idea is that, every time I add a record in jobs_config table, I need this to be reflected in java.

So, if I add a new job in the table, I want to be available without requiring app restart (of course the java code for DeleteExpiredTokenJob exists).

```
insert into jobs_config(job_name, scheduled_value) values('DeleteExpiredTokenJob', '0/5 * * * * ?');
```

Basically I need to refresh the list `List<JobsConfig>  jobsList = jobsConfigRepository.findAll();` from `listJobList()` method.

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you've tried creating a job that would refresh jobs, but it didn't work.

I can't see the simple way of making *new* job available after you added it in the DB, presuming it has a new `@Autowired` job to be injected, but I think I know how to keep track of the *updated* jobs in the db, namely the `scheduled_value` column.

1. Keep old `JobsConfig` value somehere.
2. Check if any of them changed.

   2.a. If changed, cancel the next job execution, and schedule updated one.
3. Sleep for some minutes for the next check. (Like you did in the commented code)

```java
    Map<String, JobsConfig> oldJobsConfigs = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, ScheduledFuture<?>> activeJobs = new HashMap<>()

    public void listJobList() {
        List<JobsConfig> jobsList = jobsConfigRepository.findAll();
        for (JobsConfig jobName : jobsList) {
            // If this job was there before and has not changed, do nothing.
            if (oldJobsConfigs.containsKey(jobName.getJobName()) && oldJobsConfigs.get(jobName.getJobName()).getScheduledValue().equals(jobName.getScheduledValue())) 
                break;

            // Cancel previous execution, if any.
            if (activeJobs.containsKey(jobName.getJobName()) {
                ScheduledFuture<?> job = activeJobs.get(jobName.getJobName());
                job.cancel(false);
                try {
                    job.get(); // Warning! If the job is running, blocks current thread until the job finishes. If has an endless loop, it will block current thread forever.
                } catch (CancellationException e) {
                    // Do nothing, this is good, we did not spent time waiting for the job to finish.
                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                    // Log it?
                }
            }

            ScheduledFuture<?> newJob = null;
            switch (jobName.getJobName()) {
                case "DeleteExpiredTokenJob":
                    newJob = scheduleJob(poolScheduler(), deleteExpiredTokenJob, jobName.getJobName());
                    break;
                case "TestJob":
                    newJob = scheduleJob(poolScheduler(), testJob, jobName.getJobName());
                    break;
                default:
                    logger.info(String.format("JOB NOT FOUND [%s]", jobName.getJobName()));
            }

            if (newJob != null)
                activeJobs.put(jobName.getJobName(), newJob);
        }
    }
```

And change `scheduleJob` signature so it will make use of what `scheduler` returns.

```java
    public ScheduledFuture<?> scheduleJob(TaskScheduler scheduler, JobInterface jobInterface, String jobName) {
        return scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
// ... unchanged
```

Hope that helps. :D

**UPD:**
If the number of your jobs someday grows far past ten, you can tweak `JobInterface` a bit so it will return its job name:

```java
    public interface JobInterface {
        // ... old methods
        String getJobName(); // Consider switching to enums? 
    }
```

And let Spring autowire all implementations of `JobInterface` to the `JobSchedulerService`:

```java
@Service
public class JobSchedulerService implements SchedulingConfigurer {
    @Autowired
    JobsConfigRepository jobsConfigRepository;

    @Autowired
    List<JobInterface> allJobs;
```

And then, instead of switch that had lots of entries you'll write

```java
    ScheduledFuture<?> newJob = null;
    for(JobInterface job : allJobs)
        if (job.getJobName().equals(jobName.getJobName()))
            newJob = scheduleJob(/*arguments*/);

    if (newJob == null)
        logger.warn(/*swear loudly :)*/);
```

That is, only if you want to remove this `switch`. If you plan to have little number of jobs, then leaving it as is is also ok, probably.

Comment: By the way, you may want to autowire `List<JobInterface>` to get rid of your `switch`, if you want to. Or you can even dynamically autowire it [at will](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41131440/7643283), if you manage to instrumentate new `JobInterface` implementations at runtime. It is cool but I don't know how yet. :(

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "autowire List<JobInterface> to get rid of your switch". Can you please explain?

Comment: Nice. The List<interface...> update works great. Thank you.